# Beginner Rock-Paper-Scissors game

Tags: c++, beginner, rock-paper-scissors

As a beginner, this is my second game in C++. It is a very simple rock-paper-scissors game.  User or computer wins the game after a given number of rock,paper or scissors matches. I'd appreciate any comment improving or criticising my code in any way. Thanks!

```
// Rock-Paper-Scissors game
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

char getUserInput();
char getCompInput();
void showValue(char x);
void getWinner(char x, char y);
int getScore(char x, char y);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors Game!\n";

    // Ask how many matches to play
    int matches;
    std::cout << "How many games do you want to play?: \n";
    std::cin >> matches;

    // check if user enters a valid number
    while (matches < 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid number.\n";
        std::cout << "How many games do you want to play? \n";
        std::cin >> matches;
    }

    // Play the game and get the score
    int countmatches = 0;
    int score = 0;
    while (countmatches < matches)
    {
        char player = getUserInput();
        std::cout << "You chose: ";
        showValue(player);
        char comp = getCompInput();
        std::cout << "Computer chose: ";
        showValue(comp);
        getWinner(player, comp);
        score = score + getScore(player, comp);
        countmatches++;
    }

    std::cout << matches << " matches played in total. \n";

    // Declare the winner
    if (score < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "YOU LOST THE GAME! \n";
    }
    else if (score == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "IT'S A TIE! \n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "YOU WON THE GAME! \n";
    }

    return 0;
}

// ask for user input
char getUserInput()
{
    char userInput{' '};
    std::cout << "Rock, paper or scissors? (r-p-s): \n";
    std::cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput != 'r' && userInput != 'p' && userInput != 's')
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid character. \n";
        std::cout << "Rock, paper or scissors? (r-p-s): \n";
        std::cin >> userInput;
    }
    return userInput;
}

// generate computer's choice using a random number generator
char getCompInput()
{
    std::mt19937 mt{static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
    std::uniform_int_distribution randDist{1, 3};
    int r = randDist(mt);

    switch (r)
    {
    case 1:
        return 'r';
        break;
    case 2:
        return 'p';
        break;
    case 3:
        return 's';
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

// show choice of r, p or s
void showValue(char x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case 'r':
        std::cout << "Rock\n";
        break;
    case 'p':
        std::cout << "Paper\n";
        break;
    case 's':
        std::cout << "Scissors\n";
        break;
    }
}

// find the winner
void getWinner(char x, char y)
{
    if ((x == 'r' && y == 'p') || (x == 'p' && y == 's') || (x == 's' && y == 'r'))
    {
        std::cout << "YOU LOST!\n";
    }
    else if (x == y)
    {
        std::cout << "IT'S A TIE!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "YOU WON!\n";
    }
}

// count score
int getScore(char x, char y)
{
    if ((x == 'r' && y == 'p') || (x == 'p' && y == 's') || (x == 's' && y == 'r'))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (x == y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Overview

Overall OK.

Your main issue is failure to reset the stream state on failure and assuming your human follows instructions. A bit more work there.

I rather than use a `char` to hold the state. I would use an enum

```
enum Throw {Rock, Paper, Scissors};
```

This will make the code easier to read. Also this matches up to zero/one/two so it makes accessing arrays easier (see below).

### Codereview

This looks like a C interface. Did you not want to write a C++ application?

```
char getUserInput();
char getCompInput();
void showValue(char x);
void getWinner(char x, char y);
int getScore(char x, char y);
```

---

When reading data from an untrusted source (always - but most specifically humans), you need to validate that the read worked.

```
    int matches;
    // This read assumes that the next character on the
    // input stream is a number. If it is not then the
    // read will fail (I am not sure if `matches` is set to zero
    // on a failure) but I would not make that assumption.
    // defensive coding and all.
    std::cin >> matches;

    // But even if a read failure set matches to zero.
    // A read failure will put the stream into an error state.
    // Any subsequent read operation will not work until you
    // get the stream out of the error state.
    while (matches < 1)
```

The correct way to do this is:

```
    int matches = 0;
    std::cout << "How many games do you want to play?: \n";

    do {
        if (std::cin >> matches) {
            // Read worked.
        }
        else {
            // If the failure was because of EOF.
            // Then you can't get any more input and it
            // simply fail again so exit.
            if (std::cin.eof()) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Bad EOF on input stream");
            }
            // Read failed we need to reset the state of the
            // stream before we do another read.
            std::cin.clear();
            // Since interactive user input is line based.
            // Let us ignore the rest of the line.
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        if (matches < 1) {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid number.\n";
            std::cout << "How many games do you want to play? \n";
        }
    }
    while (matches < 1);
```

---

You are making an assumption that if the user fails they will get it correct the second time. I would put that in a loop until they get it correct.

```
    if (userInput != 'r' && userInput != 'p' && userInput != 's')
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid character. \n";
        std::cout << "Rock, paper or scissors? (r-p-s): \n";
        std::cin >> userInput;
    }
```

---

Initialize this only once. Then re-use.

```
    std::mt19937 mt{static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};
```

This object is relatively expensive to create. Best to create once then reuse the same object. To do that make it a `static` object.

Also we have a random seed generator!

```
    static std::random_device  rd; 
    static std::mt19937        mt{rd()};
```

---

I think this is overly verbose.

```
    switch (r)
    {
    case 1:
        return 'r';
        break;
    case 2:
        return 'p';
        break;
    case 3:
        return 's';
        break;
    }
```

Also no need for a `break` after a `return`. I would write like this:

```
    // PS: Why 1->3 we are programmers.
    //     Numbers start at zero!
    switch (r)
    {
        case 1:  return 'r';
        case 2:  return 'p';
        case 3:  return 's';
    }
```

But I would use an array.

```
    static char result[] = {'r', 'p', 's'};
    return result[r-1];
```

---

Don't add code that will never be used.

```
    return 0;
}
```

---

Sure:

```
void showValue(char x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case 'r':
        std::cout << "Rock\n";
        break;
    case 'p':
        std::cout << "Paper\n";
        break;
    case 's':
        std::cout << "Scissors\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Rather than a switch, I would again use a data structure.

```
static std::map<char, std::string> pritty {{'r', "Rock"}, {'p', "Paper"}, {'s', "Scissors"}};

std::cout << pritty[x] << "\n";
```

---

Comment: You have a likely infinite loop when `std::cin.eof()`.  Need to check for that and bail out before calling `clear()`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I hate user input :-(

Answer (score 3):

## Stream error checking

Consider the following transcript:

```
Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors Game!
How many games do you want to play?: 
two
Please enter a valid number.
How many games do you want to play? 
2
Please enter a valid number.
How many games do you want to play?
```

Since when is `2` not a valid number?  What's going wrong?

The issue is you are not checking and clearing the "fail" state of `std::cin`.
When `std::cin >> matches` finds `two` on the input stream, it cannot convert the string `"two"` to an integer, so it enters the fail state, and ignores almost all stream operations from that point forward.  You must detect and `cin.clear()` the failure state in order to use the input stream again.

**BUT** ... there is a catch.  The `two` is still sitting on the input stream, unconsumed.  You need to discard that, or the next `cin >> matches` will immediately put the stream back in the failure state.  Use `cin.ignore(...)` to discard the bad input.

```
    while (std::cin.fail() || matches < 1)
    {
        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid number.\n";
        std::cout << "How many games do you want to play? \n";
        std::cin >> matches;
    }
```